# Displaying the count of the number of duplicate items from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've been attempting to display the count of the number of duplicate results from using `ng-repeat` to no avail.

```
<label data-ng-repeat="x in projects | unique:'b' | orderBy:'b'" >
    <input
    id="x.b"
    type="checkbox"
    ng-click="toggleSelection(x.b)" 
    ng-checked="selectedRefs.indexOf(x.b) > -1" />
    {{x.b}} 
</label>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/zhH07DSHcofTxjFiE1TG?p=preview

As seen in the Plunker, these checkboxes loop through all the 'refs' and then display a `unique` checkbox for each one. What I want to do is add a count of sorts to them to show me how many times a certain 'ref' appears next to the checkbox. A written example would be that:

123 appears twice so it would show.

123 (2)

456 appears twice so it would show.

456 (2)

654 appears thrice so it would show.

654 (3)

987 appears once so it shows as.

987 (1)

Suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function which will return the count from the controller to the view

```
$scope.getCount = function (i) {
    var iCount = iCount || 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.projects.length; j++) {
        if ($scope.projects[j].b == i) {
            iCount++;
        }
    }
    return iCount;
}
```

And in the view part, call it by passing the value you want to search: `getCount(x.b)`

```
<label data-ng-repeat="x in projects | unique:'b' | orderBy:'b'">
    <input id="x.b" type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection(x.b)" ng-checked="selectedRefs.indexOf(x.b) > -1" />{{x.b}}({{getCount(x.b)}})
</label>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/RZokiI3XeSMlZB4gi4bJ?p=info

Comment: I actually have another question if you can answer it. If I wanted to only factor in the count if the status is equal to G, what would I need to add. Would it require an if statement of sorts?

Comment: @TheLimeTrees You can do something like: <span ng-if="x.a=='G'">({{getCount(x.b)}})</span>   Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/RZokiI3XeSMlZB4gi4bJ?p=preview

Comment: @K K Actually I already worked out a solution but thanks anyway. I added: 

`&& $scope.projects[j].x.a !== 'R'` to the function.